# Invalid Operation Exception: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

When I list the data  from the table(Tips) of Type Model as a partialView I get this error .

> InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[RealEstateAspNetCore3._1.Models.Advertisement]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[RealEstateAspNetCore3._1.Models.Tip]'.

The table `Tip` (Type) contains `StatusId` as a foreign key.

Tip.cs model class:

```
    [Key] 
    public int TypeId { get; set; }
    public string TypeName { get; set; }
    public int StatusId { get; set; }
    public virtual Status Status { get; set; }
```

Status.cs

```
    [Key] 
    public int StatusId { get; set; }
    public string StatusName { get; set; }
    public List<Tip> Tips { get; set; }
```

advertisement.cs

```
    [Key]
    public int AdvId { get; set; }       
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int StatusId { get; set; }
    public int TypeId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("TypeId")]
    public Tip Tip { get; set; }
```

HomeController

```
public PartialViewResult StatusName1()
{
    string statusname1 = _context.Tips.Where(i => i.StatusId == 1)
                                      .FirstOrDefault()
                                      .ToString();
    return PartialView(statusname1);
}
```

Partial view StatusName1:

```
@model RealEstateAspNetCore3._1.Models.Tip

 <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button">
  @Model.Status.StatusName <span class="caret"></span> </a>
```

`Index.cshtml` in Index I list the advertisement tables and works well and i used model like below

```
@model IEnumerable<RealEstateAspNetCore3._1.Models.Advertisement>
```

in layout after  i call the partial  above  RenderBoy like this i get error

```
 <partial name="StatusName1" />
```

I spent two days trying to solve this, and the error stayed the same.

Thank you

Comment: The error is obvious
you are passing wrong model to partialview

Comment: You are getting this error because of this like `string statusname1 = _context.Tips.Where(i => i.StatusId == 1).FirstOrDefault().ToString();` you are returning a `string` where your `viewModel` expecting a `@model RealEstateAspNetCore3._1.Models.Tip`.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron @Hossein Than you for your feed back . i edit from `string statusname1 = _context.Tips.Where(i => i.StatusId == 1).FirstOrDefault().ToString();` to `var statusname1 = _context.Tips.Where(i => i.StatusId == 1).FirstOrDefault();` and `Tip statusname1 = _context.Tips.Where(i => i.StatusId == 1).FirstOrDefault();` and i get same error

Comment: What do you wants to returns with this `string statusname1`? Only `StatusName`? or the list of `StatusName`?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron yes i want StatusName Only

Comment: It should be like this `var statusname1 = from tip in _context.Tips
                              join sts in _context.Statuses on tip.StatusId equals sts.StatusId
                              where sts.StatusId == 1
                              select new { StatusName = sts.StatusName };`

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron i used your code and i get same error , i used this `var statusname1 = _context.Tips.Where(i => i.StatusId == 1).FirstOrDefault();`   with previous codes in asp.net mvc 5  and i used @Html.Action("StatusName1" , "Home") and worked well without error  , i put debbug point in parital view the break point dosnt work in function

Comment: Where does your partial view located?  Inside shared folder or outside shared folder?

Comment: its not about the place of partial view . its in shared folder . every time the parital page show `System.Collections.Generic.List<RealEstateAspNetCore3._1.Models.Advertisement>`   i dont want this Model i want Tip Model in Partial View .Where does this mode(advertisement)  come from ? i dont know  i use the partial in layout page and in layout page there is no model definition

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron i used Advertisement model in Index page ( List of advertisement ) only i called my partial view StatusName1 ( Tip ) in layout

Comment: thank you guys for your feedbacks it works  As Brother @Pritom Sarkar   said i  must use component view instead of partialResultView methode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assumed that your partial view name is `StatusName1`

change your code like below:-

```
public IActionResult StatusName1()
{
    var status1 = _context.Tips.Where(i => i.StatusId == 1)
                                      .FirstOrDefault();

    return PartialView("StatusName1",status1);
}
```

It will resolve your issue.

**UPDATE**

in MVC core You need to use ViewComponent instead partial view.

create a folder with the name `Components` The class must inherit from the ViewComponent. I will give this component class name `CategoryWiseMenu`

```
namespace DigitalShop.Components
{
    public class CategoryWiseMenu:ViewComponent
    {
       private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

        public CategoryWiseMenu(ApplicationDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

        public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
        {
            var c = _db.Tips.Where(i => i.StatusId == 1)
                                      .FirstOrDefault();
            return View("Default.cshtml",c);
        }
    }
}
```

`~/Views/Shared/Components/Default.cshtml`

Create `Default.cshtml` in Components folder like above path.

Demo `Default.cshtml`

```
<ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">


    @foreach (var rr in Model)
    {
        <li class="nav-item text-dark">
            <a asp-controller="" asp-action=""
                class="nav-link text-dark">@rr.TypeName</a>
        </li>
    }
    
</ul>
```

now include below code in your layout page.

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("CategoryWiseMenu")
```

now it will works fine which you want.

Comment: Thank you for your response i used this partial view to find one item Status of Real Estate  1 = For Sale 2 = For Rent i add this to tables Status and in Tips talbe StatusId is ForeignKey contains ( TypeName = House , Status = 1 (For Sale) ) like that , i change code like you write but get me same error

Comment: @SabZero it's not clear to me. I have seen, above comment, you want Tip Model in Partial View. I mean, do you want to work with Tip model property in your (StatusName1)partial view?

Comment: @Priton Sarkar Exactly i want Tip Model work in Partial View . and i called partial View in Layout ..... same code i used it in asp.net mvc5 its work well in asp.net core not

Comment: @SabZero Now it's clear. you actually will not can use partial view in layout page like .net MVC.in mvc core You need to use ```ViewComponent``` instead partial view.

Comment: @SabZero I updated my answer.please check.

Comment: @SabZero also i was given a demo in ```Default.cshtml```.

Comment: Thank you  very much it works I was expecting the asp.net mvc  codes can used in core .... finally its work :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're calling the partial view from _Layout.cshtml when you need to reference the full path of the view:

```
<partial name="~/Views/Home/StatusName1.cshtml" />
```

Replace Views/Home with whatever the folder names are in your project.  See more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-5.0#partial-tag-helper

There are model and a whole host of other issues in the snippets you've provided - I think the answer from @pritom-sarkar has addressed most of those

Comment: Yes Mr @Pritom Sarkar s answers is correct and finally it works thank you for your feedback